# How to work around Bootstrap 4 issues in SXA

Tags: sxa

We are using Sitecore 9.1 version and wanted to create a new website using Sitecore SXA. We have installed SXA 1.8 module but we have been facing an issue like All partial design and components creates unnecessary extra div. I just had a look at recent version of Sitecore SXA 1.8.1 where this issue has been resolved.

Below issue mentioned in Release Notes of SXA 1.8.1.

> When you use the Bootstrap 4 grid, an extra unwanted row class is
>   added around some placeholders.

But SXA 1.8.1 is supported only in Sitecore 9.1 Update 1. Has anyone faced this issue or has any workaround for this problem?

- Sitecore version : 9.1
- SXA version : 1.8

Comment: SXA 1.8.1 supports sitecore 9.1.0 too

Comment: I had a  look at Compatibility table. it doesn't support
https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/180187

Comment: Interesting: in the upgrade guide PDF it says "The prerequisites for running this update Sitecore Experience Platform 9.0 update 2, Sitecore XP 9.1.0, or Sitecore XP 9.1.1." I'll see if I can get someone to look at the discrepancy.

Comment: I had a look at installation document or upgrade document of SXA 1.8.1. I couldn't see any discrepency. Prerequisite is mentioned clearly like Sitecore Experience Platform 9.0 update 2 or 9.1.1. I'm still wondering why Sitecore is not giving support for Sitecore 9.1 version. 

One year ago i had same issue for SXA. They released sitecore 9 and give support for SXA 1.5 version. within few months they released SXA 1.6 but stopped giving support for Sitecore 9 version.

There's always facing similar problem when we use Sitecore initial versions.

Comment: Ah you're right, they must have updated the PDF since I downloaded it 2 weeks ago.

Comment: Got a hotfix from the sitecore support and resolved the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have faced the same issues.

We have overcome them by following below steps.

1. Navigate to /sitecore/system/Settings/Feature/Experience Accelerator/Bootstrap 4
   Duplicate that module and move it to your own folder module under Feature layer. We called it {ClientName} Bootstrap

[image]

2. Set proper Grid Definition for your newly created Grid Setup:

[image]

3. Last thing to do is to set Grid Definition properly meaning set Row Class field to “row” and remove field values for Wrapping Tag and Wrapping Class fields:

[image]

To compare, this is how it looks like with default Bootstrap 4 Grid Definition:

[image]

FE team realized this is not sufficient and we created a custom view for Container component to fix one last thing. We just added row class next to component-content div:

[image]

You can find instructions how to create custom views [on my blog](https://tothecore.sk/2019/02/25/customizing-ootb-sxa-components-with-custom-views/).

> Recommendation:
>
> This is only workaround to quickly fix this issue in SXA 1.8! I
>   strongly recommend using patch file from Sitecore Support or upgrading to SXA 1.8.1 as soon as possible as if
>   you start using this Grid system, you would need to change IDs of Grid
>   settings for every single rendering once you upgrade. Think about it!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's great.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options that I know of:

- Request patch with public ref 301904 from Sitecore Support
- Don't use the "Container" rendering, instead use "Row Splitter" only

I used the latter successfully on a project where SXA 1.8.0 was just released and we didn't have time to wait for support to give us a patch, but seeing as it's been fixed in 1.8.1 I'm sure they will be able to prepare a patch for you without too much delay.

Comment: Can you breif public ref 301904? I couldn't find any issue associated with reference number that you've given.

Comment: I dont understand your question, but you can see the ref on the 1.8.1 release notes.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.  I will request a patch

Comment: Thanks for your support. Got a fix from the sitecore team and resolved the issue :)